# phone stuck in boot loop after flashing new (stock) rom

Tags: sony-xperia-z2

I just flashed a new firmware and when the phone starts, it shows the android logo and restarts. It's stuck in a boot loop. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps are pretty much guaranteed to unf**k up your phone no matter how badly messed up it is. I speak from experience.

1. Turn off phone by pressing [hard reset button](http://sony-xperia.mobi/eng/sony-xperia-z2/231-how-to-do-a-hard-reset-and-reboot-a-sony-xperia-z2-physical-hard-reset-button-sony-xperia-z2.html).
2. Use flashtools to flash a stock ROM. Download the ftf file from here (I recommend downloading 4.4.2 as its easiest to root and you likely will be flashing something else anyway).
3. Root your device using any method.
4. Install custom recovery using app such as TWRP manager or Flashify.
5. Check if you can install custom recovery **and boot into it.**
6. If yes, use it to flash ROM of your choice and you are done. If no, proceed to step 6.
7. Follow these instruction if you can't enter recovery.

   N.B. Here is the missing [download link](https://mega.nz/#!NoVSlK5T!CPJDueW8nXiHEv-jjqo7U-CrrEa1nE2JTE8mWjn3NEs) for fix recovery.zip. Also the directions forget to mention after typing `su root` a message will have popped up on your phone you must allow.

   http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z2/general/mm-6-0-1-twrp-recovery-t3364871
8. You now have TWRP working. Use it to flash latest ROM.

Additional tips:

1. enable allow installations from unknown sources
2. enable usb debugging
3. charge phone to 100% before beginning

Comment: You should consider accepting your own answer since it obviously worked for you. Since none of the answers have an up vote, this question keeps popping up to home page! Besides, visitors do not know which answer works. Accepting would solve both :)

Answer (score 0):

Factory reset solves this issue most of the times. Use hard ware keys to get in reset menu and factory reset your phone.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: http://sony-xperia.mobi/eng/sony-xperia-z2/231-how-to-do-a-hard-reset-and-reboot-a-sony-xperia-z2-physical-hard-reset-button-sony-xperia-z2.html

Comment: Please follow the above link. I think you need not boot into recovery. That seems the way on your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue. You can **solve** it **by wiping out** the system of device.

***Steps for wiping:***

**1.** Use the Volume keys in order to navigate through the recovery menu.

**2.** Select “advanced” and choose “wipe dalvik cache”.

**3.** Return to main menu.

**4.** Then select “wipe data factory reset”.

**5.** Return and this time choose “wipe cache partition”.

**6.** Return and select “reboot system now”.

**7.** Your handset should start in Android OS now.

This will hopefully, solve your problem. **It worked me** as well.

**In case you can't boot into recovery**, you can physically hard reset by following this [Link](http://sony-xperia.mobi/eng/sony-xperia-z2/231-how-to-do-a-hard-reset-and-reboot-a-sony-xperia-z2-physical-hard-reset-button-sony-xperia-z2.html)

**For advanced solution**, you can follow this [Link](http://xda-university.com/as-a-user/how-to-recover-from-a-bootloop)

Comment: I can't boot into recovery.

Comment: You cant boot into recovery? 0_0..
Do you know correct keys for booting into recovery? 
It is :
Power on and when the LED Notification lights up you need to press several times Volume Up or Volume Down, either one works.
For Xperia Z2.

Comment: I can't get it to recovery. No LED light turns on. I try pressing volume up and volume down when the phone turns on, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There's no built-in, functional recovery for Xperia devices AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you could have a corrupt image. Make sure you get an MD5 or similar for your image. Make sure if you are flashing a new rom that you are wiping Data, Cache, Dalvik-Cache, and System manually before flashing a new ROM.